# Globally Handle Exceptions in JSF2

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I want to send the user to one error page whenever an error occurs, whether it be a 404, 500..etc.  I was using the error-code in the web.xml but I want to trap all instances of java.lang.Throwable since I believe any error is a subclass of java.lang.Throwable.  Also, when I used the error-code scheme, the stacktraces were not appearing in Tomcat's catlina.out anymore...any ideas?  I wasn't sure if JSF2's ExceptionHandler API handled 404s?

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/pageNotFound.html</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/systemError.html</location>
  </error-page>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're struggling with? That isn't entirely clear from the question. Is the concrete problem that the stacktrace isn't printed anymore whenever you specified a custom HTTP 500 error page? That shouldn't happen. There would be more into the problem.

Comment: the problem is the stack trace is not printing any longer for 500s when I just trap the error codes in the web.xml. I thought there may be a better way than what I'm doing.  I've posted my web.xml code above now...any suggestions?

Comment: So, when you remove alone that 500 entry from `web.xml`, then the stacktrace is been printed? What Tomcat version are you using?

Comment: it seems to be printing now either way so it must have been some sort of temporary issue.  Another question I really wanted to know is how can I just trap all exceptions?  I don't want to have to list all of the HTTP error codes that I may get.

Comment: Exceptions only end up as HTTP 500, so it's sufficient to specify only that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *when I used the error-code scheme, the stacktraces were not appearing in Tomcat's catlina.out anymore*

This is not the standard behaviour. Your problem is caused by something else. Perhaps it's the wrong testing methodology or perhaps you're suppressing exceptions and manually redirecting in some `Filter` or like. This is impossible to answer based on the as far provided information.

---

> *I wasn't sure if JSF2's ExceptionHandler API handled 404s?*

Depends. If the request URL matches the `FacesServlet`, then it would by default throw a `FileNotFoundException` which eventually ends up as HTTP 500. If the request URL does not match the `FacesServlet` or any other servlet, then the servlet container will handle it as HTTP 404.